# Django - how to modify crispy forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

First, I want to generate a page that looks like this:

[image]

There are three things that makes it difficult. 
1. Label + Input field set should line up horizontally
2. Some of the fields have checkbox
3. Date Field has a special Bootstrap plugin.

Here are the html source code for each types:

**generic type:**

```
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
      <label class="input-upper-title">Drill String Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="" class="form-control  input-field-height-vertical" name="" required="">
    </div>
```

**has checkbox:**

```
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
      <label class="input-upper-title">String Length (ft)</label>
      <div class="has-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="" class="form-control input-field-height-vertical input-calculated" name="" data-parsley-trigger="" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**has date plugin:**

```
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
      <label class="input-upper-title">Date Run</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker7" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input input-field-height-vertical" data-target="#datetimepicker7"/>
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker7" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my **forms.py**:

```
class BHA_overall_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    prefix = 'bha_overall'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()

    class Meta():
        model = BHA_overall
        fields = '__all__'
```

How should I modify my **forms.py**, using `crispy_forms` to get the same effect as my html source code does?